# Disk Image of an old XP box

Tags: windows

I have an old XP box that I use as a mini server for old and light stuff. This box is on my network but not near me.

My main computer today is an iMac and I access the XP box using the network.

I am right now installing XP on that box again, due to corruption problems. My idea is to create an image of the main disk and be able to restore it from the network, when needed.

My questions is:

- is it possible to create/restore an image of xp disk thru the network using a mac os x box?

What I need is a kind of time machine for windows that can work, if possible, thru the network.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a simple, low-cost solution and don't mind setting up an FTP server to host the disk images or boot into the backup software from CD, take a look at [g4u](http://www.feyrer.de/g4u/).

If you want a few more bells and whistles including a range of storage options and incremental or differential backups to keep your image updated, consider paying a bit for [Acronis True Image Home](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/) and the [Plus Pack](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/plus-pack.html).